# How to require multiple interfaces in F# when a parameter is an object type?

Tags: scala, f#

In scala, I can require multiple traits like this:

```
def foo(bar: Foo with Bar): Unit = {
  // code
}
```

Is this also possible in F#, or do I have to explicitly declare a `FooBar` interface that inherits `Foo` and `Bar`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify this by having a generic type `'T` with constraints that restrict `'T` to types that implement the required interfaces.

For example, given the following two interfaces:

```
type IFoo = 
  abstract Foo : int 
type IBar = 
  abstract Bar : int
```

I can write a function requiring `'T` which is `IFoo` and also `IBar`:

```
let foo<'T when 'T :> IFoo and 'T :> IBar> (foobar:'T) = 
  foobar.Bar + foobar.Foo
```

Now I can create a concrete class implementing both interfaces and pass it to my `foo` function:

```
type A() = 
  interface IFoo with 
    member x.Foo = 10
  interface IBar with 
    member x.Bar = 15

foo (A()) // Type checks and returns 25
```